# Redirect using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect all traffic from the root of my website to a subfolder on the same domain using .htaccess

Can someone help me out here?

Answer (score 1):

Place this in your webroot .htaccesss

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subfolder/ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subfolder/$1 [L]
```

It checks incoming requests, any to that domain get redirected, unless they are already redirected.

Comment: There would not seem to be any need to check the `HTTP_HOST` in this instance - it's all on one domain.

Comment: You're probably right mate. Is this from 2010? Holy heck.

Answer (score 0):

Theres an excellent guide here: [mod_rewrite, a beginner’s guide (with examples)](http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/scripting/mod_rewrite).